# Oracle trigger when null custom word?

Tags: c#, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER auto_id
before insert on CustomWord
for each row
declare
    max_id number;
    cur_seq number;
begin
    if :new.table_id1, :new.table_id2,  :new.table_id3,  :new.table_id4 is null then
--HERE what should I get it?  Something  like tableid1 value = "it's ok"

        end loop;
    end if;
end;
/
```

I just want to create trigger when user's get null value on "table_id1" it's value changed automatically insert just "It's ok". How to create like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it by trigger (for whatever reason), it's as simple as that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER auto_id
before insert on CustomWord
for each row
begin
    if :new.table_id1 is null then
      :new.table_id1 := 'it''s ok';
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: thanks that what I need.. Why did you asking "really want"? Or is it good to use another method?

And how to use this trigger include all columns?

Comment: "Really want" because setting a default value in the table specification is easier. To do this for all columns, create copies of the `if ... end if` block and change the column name (both in the `if`condition and in the assignment). AFAIK there is no way to loop over all columns.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use default value on column:

```
create table CustomWord 
...   
 table_id1 varchar2(30) default 'Ok',
...
```

Instead of trigger. Note that you then need to omit the columns from INSERT statement when they are `NULL` unless you have Oracle 12c in which you can use the DEFAULT ON NULL clause.

With default on null clause:

```
create table CustomWord 
...   
 table_id1 varchar2(30) default on null 'Ok',
```

To modify existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE CustomWord MODIFY(table_id1 DEFAULT on null 'It''s ok');
```

However, I recommend to not insert the "It's ok" string as it is better to keep the NULL value as an evidence that it is ok. Human readable presentation that it is ok should be made based on the fact that the value is null.

Comment: So in this case how to create default value? Can describe me more specific?
I just read http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1.php But I don't get it

Comment: Updated. Note that the `INSERT` statement needs to be modified to omit the concerned columns in this solution alternative. It depends if that is suitable. You could argue that you could then as well modify the `INSERT` to insert a certain string instead of `NULL` as well.

Comment: You would end up having null if your insert statement explicitly inserts NULL. An alternative to trigger is also to do INSERT NVL(table_id1,'It''s ok') into CustomWord. Personally I would not insert this is ok string. Why do you want it? It is stricter in logic to check for null than a certain string. You can present the string to the user based on the null using NVL or by using a view.

Comment: The problem with omiting the columns in the insert statement is that many people often use ORMs that don't do that.

Comment: @ammoQ: I understand that using default value might not be feasible.

Comment: @All Solution: In the case you are using Oracle 12c you can use the default on null clause and you do not need to omit the null columns.

Comment: @ammoQ: Found that Oracle 12c has a default on null clause.

Comment: Interesting, but obviously that could be cause compatibility issues when upgrading to 12c. Good to know, thanks!